# C# ListView Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, listview, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag and drop a `ListViewItem` from one `ListView` to another in a Windows Form Application. I have two `ListViews` : `lvImageFolder` and `lvWebServer`. I am trying to drag from `lvImageFolder` to `lvWebServer`.

My code is shown below :

```
private void lvImageFolder_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        txtCursor.Text = Cursor.Position.ToString();
        lvWebServer.DoDragDrop(lvImageFolder.Items[0].Text, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

}

private void lvWebServer_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string dragToItem = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();

    lvWebServer.Items.Add(dragToItem);
}

private void lvWebServer_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }   
}
```

The issue I am having is that the string `dragToItem` is empty. I have tried passing in a serialized object to the `DoDragDrop` method also but this gave me nothing but issues.

Can anyone please shed any light on this issue?

Comment: I notice in `lvImageFolder_MouseDown` you're always using the text of the first element in the list.  Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line below it works, but as adv12 wrote, copy always the first item:

```
lvWebServer.DoDragDrop(lvImageFolder.Items[0].ToString(), DragDropEffects.Move);
```

Change it to the code below to dragdrop the selected element:

```
lvWebServer.DoDragDrop(lvImageFolder.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you start drag and drop with list view item position [0], and possibly it's an empty item. You should start drag and drop with list view's selected items, for instance:

```
private void lvImageFolder_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        //txtCursor.Text = Cursor.Position.ToString();
        if (lvImageFolder.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var lst = new List<string>();
            foreach (ListViewItem item in lvImageFolder.SelectedItems)
            {
                lst.Add(item.Text);
            }
            lvWebServer.DoDragDrop(lst, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

}

private void lvWebServer_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> lst = e.Data.GetData(typeof(List<string>)) as List<string>;
    foreach (var item in lst)
    {
        lvWebServer.Items.Add(item);
    }

}

private void lvWebServer_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(List<string>)))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}
```